# Appcelerator Titanium Android Splash Screen seen Twice / Flashing

Tags: android, titanium, appcelerator

anyone have any idea why my splash screen shows twice when my app starts? I see the splash screen / startup screen and then it flashes again with a transition effect and then the app loads - I did not have this problem before Titanium 6 SDK.

This happens on Android using Titanium 6.1.2 SDK

Comment: Please show some code..

Comment: have you used the `LaunchScreen`.

Comment: This is a massive app - not sure what part of the code you would want. Also Launch Screen is for iOS - this is an Android Problem I am seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I have narrowed this down to actually being due to the way Appcelerator Studio starts the app when using the RUN function. This does not happen if the app gets installed via the APK and then run from the App Icon.

Answer (score 0):

There where many changes to the start-up in 6.1.0.GA and in 6.1.2.GA (e.g. https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/pull/9256). What you see is a restart. You should see some log in Android Monitor/logcat.

It sometimes happen in my app when they got killed in the background. Before the fixes you would see the app starting up and then closing again and after many seconds it would start again. But in the newer releases you just see the flash. But again: shouldn't happen all the time, only when the app got killed

Comment: If its what you are referring to I see that it should log 
`Log.w(TAG, "Runtime has been disposed or app has been killed. Finishing.");` - but I am not seeing that log anywhere even when checking in  Android Monitor

Comment: Could it be splash screen and then app/activity background or something like that? Maybe there is a delay in my DrawerLayout opening then we see the activity background that is the same as the splash screen?

Comment: Hi - it seems like it is problem with drawerlayout on android where it takes a while to open - this causes the activity background to be shown and then only after a second the drawer opens - the problem is that there is a transition effect when the activity opens and it then looks like the splash screen is shown twice, as the activity background (default.png) is the same as the splash screen - is there a way to
1. prevent the main activity from opening until the drawer is ready?
OR
2. Remove the main activity opening transition effect?

Comment: setting this style item on my theme has removed the transition effect - its better now but there is still a slight flash as it moves from the splash screen to first activity

`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>`

Comment: Also this only happens the VERY FIRST TIME the app opens